# Redirección a pasarela de pago y guardar modelo en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un sistema de citas médicas en la que el usuario debe hacer un pago con tarjeta de crédito, y una vez efectuada, si ha sido satisfactoria, se hace el guardado en el modelo de citas.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

       $appointment = new Appointment();
            $appointment->appointments_status_id = 1;
            $appointment->professionals_id = $request['professionals_id'];
            $appointment->date = $request['date'];
    
      $PayIn = new \MangoPay\PayIn();
            $PayIn->CreditedWalletId = 123123123;
            $PayIn->AuthorId = Auth::user()->mangopay_id;
            $PayIn->PaymentType = \MangoPay\PayInPaymentType::Card;
            $PayIn->PaymentDetails = new \MangoPay\PayInPaymentDetailsCard();
            $PayIn->PaymentDetails->CardType = "CB_VISA_MASTERCARD";
            $PayIn->DebitedFunds = new \MangoPay\Money();
            $PayIn->DebitedFunds->Currency = "EUR";
            $PayIn->DebitedFunds->Amount = $amount;
            $PayIn->Fees = new \MangoPay\Money();
            $PayIn->Fees->Currency = "EUR";
            $PayIn->Fees->Amount = 0;
            $PayIn->ExecutionType = \MangoPay\PayInExecutionType::Web;
            $PayIn->ExecutionDetails = new \MangoPay\PayInExecutionDetailsWeb();
            $PayIn->ExecutionDetails->ReturnURL = "http" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "s" : null) . "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] . "?stepId=" . (0 + 1);
            $PayIn->ExecutionDetails->Culture = "ES";
            $result = $this->mangopay->PayIns->Create($PayIn);
 
return redirect($result->ExecutionDetails->RedirectURL)->with('success', 'Cita Concertada Correctamente');
            $appointment->saveOrFail();
    
            return (redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Cita Concertada Correctamente'));
}
```

La pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo controlar que solo se reserve la cita si el pago ha sido satisfactorio?  La redirección me la da la plataforma de pago que utilizo, Mangopay.

Gracias.

Comment: Supongo que estas usando una API, solo haz que cuando la API te devuelva el codigo de pago aceptado despues registres la reserva a dicho cliente

Comment: Pero la redirección hacía la pasarela de pago la hace la plataforma, yo quiero que si es satisfactoria se guarde los datos. No tengo forma de capturar la respuesta, gracias.